# Firefox add-on builder and Jquery Mobile

Tags: firefox, jquery-mobile, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying everything under my power here to insert jquerymobile.1.0.1 into an extension I have build for firefox.

I can install, link to any other script and everything seems to work just fine, but have had an assortment of errors getting jquerymobile to work.

I've tried uploading through the add-on builder
I've tried remotely linking the file
I've tried copying and pasting the file into other code.. nothing works.

I've coded this extension for safari, chrome and opera without issue, but Firefox chokes the second I link to/include jquerymobile in my code returning this error:

Timestamp: 12-04-27 12:10:33 PM
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHistory.replaceState]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://jid0-d4zlaxz3cfuahkcdoecsmya637m-at-jetpack/idesireit/data/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js ::  :: line 72"  data: no]

and also an error about "unallowed unicode" which I didn't get the chance to copy or paste, but I haven't seen that one in a few saves...

I've read that the above error can be caused by cross domain functions, but all my cross domain functions are in another js file, and they are all working just fine ( judging by those I can navigate to with jquerymobile acting as it is right now )

I'm a novice - if my error is based on my stupidity, please go lightly :O

Comment: That error comes from a call to [`window.history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history#replaceState). What is your extension doing when it happens? Ideally, you should edit your question and insert the relevant code part. PS: Never mind, `history.pushState` support code calls it when initializing itself.

Comment: Well, it does this regardless if I ever call any code,

Comment: the only code I have calling jquerymobile at this point is the 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://site.com/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://site.com/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
it handles only the UI-UX features 

if I remove all other calls to any other function code so no file files any functions at all.. and only leave jquerymobile and my HTML ( plain HTML ) I get the same error

Comment: so the correct answer to your question " What is the extension doing", would be nothing... or loading, either are accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created an all new extension, 
included nothing but the popup, and in that pop up, called jquery and jquery.mobile.

I got this error instantly again.

I'm just going to go ahead and use the alternative UI I'm using on the dashboard widget, I've wasted too much time on this.

Comment: it wld have been easier to debug using the non-minified version of jq mobile. It's possible the proxy the SDK uses between the content script code and the real DOM is causing problems here.

Comment: I came across this in some searching : 

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=593910
and modified the code to create a work around that works great, error free..

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in the addonsdk, not in JQ Mobile. Any attempt to access or manipulate the window.history object in a panel will raise this error.